# Run python in Tauri

Tags: python, python-3.x, tauri

How am I able to execute a python function including parameters with tauri? I have seen other posts stating to use sidecars, although I'm not sure how to work with those aswell.

Answer (score 0):

1. You include the python binary and python files with your app. Then you will declare a tauri handler in the `src-tauri` directory that uses `std::process::Command` to start the python binary with your desired python file and capture the result through standard output.
2. You can use a crate like `py03` to link python to your tauri binary and communicate with python through the rust foreign function interface.

I would recommend using rust directly for any functionality to avoid these complexities.